# How can I access the collection list?

Tags: anylogic

In the AnyLogic environment, the nodes are stored in the collection as shown in the figure and there are 3 initial agents of people2s. I want to solve the problem by getting each node value from the collection so that the first agent goes to the first node and the second agent goes to the second node. How do we solve the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For-loop is your friend:

```
for (RectangularNode currentNode : collection) {
    // do whatever you like with the currentNode
}
```

Next, start understanding more Java for AnyLogic: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/index.html